# RunAsync() inside a for-loop

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, winrt-async

https://github.com/Sangeepan/stackoverflow_github (test project that generates this error)

The following code generates error:

**An unhandled exception of type 'System.StackOverflowException' occurred in mscorlib.dll**

```
    private async void updateUserlist(String userlist)
    {
        var jsonArray = JArray.Parse(userlist);

        foreach (var jsonobjects in jsonArray)
        {
            var item = jsonobjects["Id"];
            await Dispatcher.RunAsync(CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, () => main_userlist.Items.Add(item));
        }
    }
```

When I replace the await line with Debug.Writeline(item) it works fine.

Comment: So is adding an item to the list in any way doing something that would result in another call to this method, thus causing indirect recursion?

Comment: no, adding item to a ListView is just going to add a new item.

Comment: here is the input to the method incase you want to try it out.
[
  {
    "Id": "7eb61673-f573-4c75-a585-fdede728eabd",
    "Username": "127.0.0.1"
  }
]

Answer (score 1):

This can happen if the task you're awaiting completes too quickly and you have a lot of items to process.

Make your `async` calls more "chunky" (and therefore slower):

```
private async Task updateUserlistAsync(String userlist)
{
  var jsonArray = JArray.Parse(userlist);
  var jsonobjects = jsonArray.Select(jsonobjects => jsonobjects["Id"]).ToArray();
  await Dispatcher.RunAsync(CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, () =>
  {
    foreach (var item in jsonobjects)
    {
      main_userlist.Items.Add(item);
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: I understand your way of thinking and I will use that in future but your method still gives the same error.

Comment: @RedHotScalability Then why are you dispatching to the UI thread; you're already there.

Comment: sorry guys, I am new at Winrt and c#. I tried to run it without async/await and it gave me error about call being marshalled for different thread so I guess I wasnt in UI thrad afterall.

Comment: I think we'll need a minimal repro to fix the issue.

Comment: okey, i will upload a small project that generates the error to Github. Hang on

Answer (score 0):

Problem is solved. I needed to add toString() to the json Object. Sometimes the error message in VS12 can misguide you. When I googled the stackoverflow error message it was all about infinite loops and threads.

main_userlist.Items.Add(item.toString());